# Prioritise nested route over main route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

### **Setup**

I have an `App` component rendering following routes:

```
<Route path="/items/:id" component={ItemDetail} />
<Route path="/items" component={AllItems} />
```

In my `AllItems` component I render a list of all items and the option to create a new item or update an existing one. Doing either one of those actions opens a popup. To do this I render following routes in `AllItems`:

```
<Route path="/items/add" component={AddItemModal} />
<Route path="/items/edit" component={EditItemModal} />
```

*Note: It's important that these modals are actually linked to these routes, I can't change that. Neither can I render those routes outside of `AllItems` as I need to pass soms props to the modals.*

---

### **Problem**

When I go to a route like `/items/1`: `ItemDetail` renders (as expected).

When I go to `/items/add`: `ItemDetail` renders with `add` as `:id`.
I need it to render `AddItemModal` here as defined in `AllItems`.

**What I tried:**

- I tried adding `exact` to the `/items/:id` route and I also tried adding it to `/items/add` & `/items/edit`. Neither of those solutions worked. Either only `ItemDetail` rendered, or only the modals.
- I tried defining `/items` before `/items/:id` to hopefully give higher priority to the nested routes. `ItemDetail` never rendered in this case.

Is there a solution to this so I can prioritise `items/add` & `items/edit` over `items/:id`

Comment: If you put `exact` attribute to your route does it solve your problem ?

Comment: I think you can place the `Route` in the order according to your priority.

Comment: @MaximeGirou I have tried adding `exact` to `/items/:id` the problem remains the same. I also tried adding it to the `/items/add` and `/items/edit` route. The problem still remains the same. I guess this is because the `AllItems` component which renders those routes isn't rendered at all in this case.

Comment: The route for editing shouldn't be something in the lines of `/items/:id/edit`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try nesting the routes under `/items`

```
<Route
path="/items"
render={() => (
  <>
    <Route path="" component={AllItems} exact />
    <Route path="/add" component={AddItemModal} />
    <Route path="/edit" component={EditItemModal} />
    <Route path="/:id" component={ItemDetail} />
  </>
)}
/>
```

Comment: there is no reason to do it nested like this, the only thing that matters is the order

Comment: @Mykybo In my case there was, as I noted in my question I needed props from the `AllItems` component to correctly render the `add` and `edit` modal. So the `add` and `edit` route had to be rendered in that component.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have an independent views for `ItemDetail` and `AllItems` but at the same time have `/items/add` and `/items/:id/edit` (took a little liberty with the url, you need and id to edit an item right?) as modals over `AllItems` so the structure of the routes would be something like this:

- `AllItemsView` (/items)

  - `AddItemModal` (/items/new)
  - `EditItemModal` (/items/:id/edit)
- `ItemDetailView` (/items/:id)

You need a little tweak of [Tnc Andrei](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58995664/3848267) response:

```
  <Route
    path="/items"
    render={({ match: {url, isExact}, location: {pathname} }) => {
      let pathnameArray = pathname.split("/")
      let lastChunk = pathnameArray[pathnameArray.length - 1]
      if (isExact || lastChunk === "new" || lastChunk === "edit") {
        return (
          <>
            <Route path={`${url}/`} component={CompetitionsView} />
            <Switch>
              <Route path={`${url}/new`} component={CompetitionFormModal} />
              <Route path={`${url}/:competitionId/edit`} component={CompetitionFormModal} />
            </Switch>
          </>
        )
      }
      return (
        <>
          <Route path={`${url}/:competitionId`} component={CompetitionView} />
        </>
      )
    }}
  />
```